# Set from a diophantine equation with similar statistics to primes

Tags: analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, sequences-and-series, diophantine-equations

While doing some computational calculations with some diophantine equations, I came across with some sequences from solutions of quartic and quintic equations with slowly decreasing frequency, similar to the observed with the sequences of primes. I'll focus the question in one of these equations.

Let be $S$ and $T$ the sets defined by the following

$$S=\{y \in \mathbb{N} : \exists x,z \in \mathbb{N} \land x \geq 2 \quad s.t. \quad x^5-x^2+y^2=z^2\}$$
$$T=\{z \in \mathbb{N} : \exists x,y \in \mathbb{N} \land x \geq 2 \quad s.t. \quad x^5-x^2+y^2=z^2\}$$

and

$$s(m,A)=\sum_{n \in A, n \leq m}1$$
$$r(m,A)=\sum_{n \in A, n \leq m} \frac{1}{n}$$
where $A$ is a set of positive integers

I propose the following conjecture

> Conjecture:
> $$s(m,S)\sim c_{S}\frac{m}{\log(m)} \quad s(m,T)\sim c_{T}\frac{m}{\log(m)} $$
> $$r(m,S)\sim d_{S}\log\log(m) \quad r(m,T)\sim d_{T}\log\log(m)$$
> for some constants $c_{S},d_{S},c_{T},d_{T}$

The conjecture is supported with experimental data, here I compiled plots of $\frac{s(m,A)}{\frac{m}{\log(m)}}$

[image]
[image]

The distribution of the solutions of the described equation depends of the set of divisors of $x^2$ and $x^3-1$, but I can't find good counting arguments relating the two of them for every $x$. Since I don't have an idea of how difficult a proof of the conjecture could be or if it's sharp enough, I have the following question:

> Question: Is there any heuristic that can complement the experimental data to refine the conjecture?

Comment: By partial summation, the second display in the conjecture follows from the first display (with $d_S=c_S$ and $d_T=c_T$).

Comment: The graphs seem to indicate that the conjecture is wrong as they appear to go to zero rather than to a limit. Or am I misunderstanding something?